# Average UV Islands equivalent for averaging faces?

Tags: modeling, faces

Is there a way to average faces on a model in the way average UV islands works?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the remesh modifier?

Comment: Thanks Reaper! Hmm it looks like remesh kind of works for averaging faces but it really messes up the current topology. Is there anything that adjusts the existing topology to make quads more uniform everywhere?

Comment: I think your only choice is to either use an automated re-meshing or doing it by hand. For the automated side, you can either use the remesh modifier (like you did) or you could use zRemesher (if you can get your hand on zBrush). zRemesher is one of the best topo-tools available, sadly it only comes with zBrush. However, there's an alternative to zRemesher. A small tool called instant meshes, which should do a good job too. https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes

Oh, and you could maybe give Simplygon a try. It looks pretty cool.